# Chatbox constaly scrolling down in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chatroom that pulls chat down with the code below.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#chat-area').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#chat-area')[0].scrollHeight
    }, 800);
}, 300);
```

How can I stop it from pulling down if someone is trying to scroll up?

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: This mechanism is a bit more complex than it might appear on first glance. You need to figure out the exact policy. The basic idea is to scroll down automatically right after new chat lines were added, but only if the chat area was scrolled all the way to the bottom right before its size changed. Use variables to keep track of the state (`var is_alltheway_down = false;` etc) and only do stuff automatically if the variable state indicates it's fine.

Comment: @Kinduser https://jsfiddle.net/kkrbmzqn/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the idea.  I worked on it using this idea, and eventually got it to work! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i think could be done:

1. clear interval
2. use [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) de jquery
3. use a semaphore